# How to save default action chosen by user in chooserActivity

Tags: android

I want to save default action chosen by user on clicking checkbox after launching available applications using ResolverActivity.java. I have gone through ResolverActivity.java, below chunk of code does get execute but still the default action is not saved. And next time i need to choose action/application all over again.

Code :

```
getPackageManager().addPreferredActivity(filter, bestMatch, set,
                     intent.getComponent());
```

Can anybody tell me whats the reason behind this code not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android security policy will prohibit you from changing preferred activities, except that if your activity has been set as default you may unset that default.

If you just need a default for your own app, you'll have to write all the code to handle this yourself.  Create your own dialog with a list of options to choose from, your own checkbox to remember the setting, your own code to save & load that default, etc.

Comment: I have an envelope key on my keyboard, i am using resolveractivity to give all messaging apps as options to user. User can select any messaging type viz. SMS, Email,Gmail, Whatsapp etc, and make it as default by clicking the checkbox "Set this as Deault". But my problem is : This default action chosen by user is not getting saved, and again when user press Envelope key,he needs to select from list of options. From where defaults are restored in android?

Comment: To let the user set a default for your app, you can't use ResolverActivity.  You're gonna have to do all the work yourself.  Use PackageManager.queryIntentActivities() to get a list of options, display then to the user in a ListView, save the result to a SharedPreferences, etc.  I won't do all this for you, but if you get half of it done and get stuck, post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Third party apps cannot control the default apps for any action due to security reasons. Only the system may alter these settings.